# securing a file on disk with password protection usig strong ssl cipher and view the file in more secured way

Tags: files, encryption

I was trying to decrypt a file to standard out and pipe its content to a given commmand. For example, the `cat` command, `wc` command etc. However,, I felt the following command can be simplified; any further thoughts?

```
echo "openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in "$(read -p "enter file:" fp && echo \"$fp\")" -k "$(read -s -p "enter passwd:" pswd && echo \"$pswd\")" -d | "$(read -p "enter command:" cmd && echo \"$cmd\")" " | xargs -0 -I{} /usr/bin/bash -c {}
```

For sake of completeness, commands to encrypt and decrypt a file, for example:

#### encrypt a file (password protected)

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in in.txt -out out.txt -e
```

#### decrypt a file

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in out.txt -k hello -d
```

of course we could use any supported cipher.

Answer (score 1):

You're making it unnecessarily complex. You just need a couple of handy functions:

```
enc () {openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in "$@"}
dec () {openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in "$@"}
```

If you don't give `openssl` a password or key it will prompt you for one, which means you don't have to build it into your command.

To encrypt a file:

```
enc foo > foo.enc
```

To decrypt file:

```
dec foo.enc
```

Which naturally can be piped to other commands:

```
dec foo.enc | wc -l
```

Comment: Aliases don't expand `$@` in the shells I'm aware of; they simply replace the leading text, leaving any arguments in-place. Mentioning this just because of the `$@` in the alias definition.

Comment: Good point, switched to functions.

Answer (score 0):

From a programming point of view you should separate the bussiness logic from the ui. Simply decrypt the file and build the options in another place.